# Remove <div> with js (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, button, web

I want to remove a `<div>` from the page, when the user clicks a button.

Javascript:

```
var close = function(element) {
        element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
```

Close button:

```
<div id="close" onclick='close(this)'>X</div>
```

The close button is inside a parent div.

When i click the button, nothing happens.

The entire page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            position:absolute;
            background-color: teal;
        }
        #dragc{
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;     
            user-select: none;
        }
        #header{
            position: relative;
            background: black; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* Standard syntax */
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;     
            user-select: none;
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        #taskbar{
            position: absolute;
            background: black; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#202020, black); /* Standard syntax */
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;     
            user-select: none;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 35px;
        }
        #close{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            background: red;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, #800000); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(red, #800000); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, #800000); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(red, #800000); /* Standard syntax */
            color: white;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: consolas;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    var close = function(element) {
        element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
        var mydragg = function() {
return {
move: function(divid, xpos, ypos) {
  divid.style.left = xpos + 'px';
  divid.style.top = ypos + 'px';
},
startMoving: function(divid, container, evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var rec = divid.getBoundingClientRect();
  var posX = evt.clientX,
    posY = evt.clientY,
    divTop = rec.top,
    divLeft = rec.left,
    eWi = parseInt(divid.style.width),
    eHe = parseInt(divid.style.height),
    cWi = parseInt(document.getElementById(container).style.width),
    cHe = parseInt(document.getElementById(container).style.height);
  var diffX = posX - divLeft,
    diffY = posY - divTop;
  document.onmousemove = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var posX = evt.clientX,
      posY = evt.clientY,
      aX = posX - diffX,
      aY = posY - diffY;
    if (aX < 0) aX = 0;
    if (aY < 0) aY = 0;
    if (aX + eWi > cWi) aX = cWi - eWi;
    if (aY + eHe > cHe) aY = cHe - eHe;
    mydragg.move(divid.parentNode, aX, aY);
  }
},
stopMoving: function(container) {
  document.onmousemove = function() {}
},
}
}();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container' style="width: 100%;height: 100%;top:0px;left:0px;">
        <div id="taskbar">

        </div>
        <div id="dragc" style="width: 200px;height: 100px; left: 30%; top: 20%;">
            <div id="header" onmousedown='mydragg.startMoving(this,"container",event);' onmouseup='mydragg.stopMoving("container");'>

            </div>
            <div id="close" onclick='close(this)'>X</div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onClick="remove(this.parentNode)">...</a>
</div>
<script>
function remove(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
</script>
```

> Use This as it is :)

Answer (score 1):

simply use :

```
document.getElementById('close').remove();
```

or you can use

```
document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(event){
  let elem = document.getElementById(event.target.id)
  elem.remove ? elem.remove() : elem.removeNode();
}
```

Comment: remove(); is not supported by all browsers.
The problem is the function's name, not the removing method.

Comment: I added the use of removeNode for IE, tell me if another browser is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="close" onclick='close(this.id)'>X</div>
function remove(id) {
var elem = document.getElementById(id);
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Yes, we would like to see, why does this code works while the other not.

Comment: because in other's code they are sending remove(this)or emove(this.parentNode) in and i am sending this.id means current div id it is a simple logic

Comment: and if you want to use to remove(this) then you have to do like this in your remove() function   ----function   remove(par){  var id = par.id;console.log(id);console.log(par); }   you can see the result in console what var par and id have

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the name "close" refers to something else when executing javascript code in your browser, therefore your onclick event doesn't get called. You have to rename your function to something else to make it work.

However, your code still will not work although it'll be called on onclick event now. You'll have to modify it to something like this;

```
function(element) {
    element.parentNode.remove(element);
}
```